# OpenVPN on virtualized TrueNAS Bad routing?

Tags: openvpn

I have the following, very weird problem.
I've set up an OpenVPN server, i can connect, and ping remote LAN's ip addresses. Well most of.
There are two clients that are inaccessible to vpn clients.

My OpenVPN server configuration:
TUN/Subnet
push "route 192.168.1.0 255.255.255.0"
push "dhcp-option DNS 10.100.0.1"
push "dhcp-option DNS 192.168.1.20"

The VPN Server is at 10.100.0.0/24
The Main Subnet is 192.168.1.0/24

After i connect from a remote:
Ping from Remote Client:

192.168.1.1 (TCP:80) a router
192.168.1.10 (TCP 80/443 etc.) ESXi machine
192.168.1.20 PiHole (DHCP+DNS) **sometimes** does not accessible (Virtualized)
192.168.1.220 (Windows 10 Pro) after some configuration in the firewall it's accessible
192.168.1.22 (Windows 10 Pro) virtualized, same configuration, **non-accessible**
192.168.1.21 TrueNAS (80/443 etc.) virtualized accessible. **The VPN server run on this machine.**

From the TrueNAS:
I can ping eveything.

From a random other machine on the remote LAN:
10.100.0.1 accessible
10.100.0.2 (the connected client) is not.

Thanks for helping!

Answer (score 0):

I believe it has something to do with the Routing Policy on your client. Try `ip route`on your client or equivalent Windows command and see what subnets it routes are via VPN server, and what aren't. If you have chosen to route virtually everything (sometimes only except localhost 127.0.0.1) via the VPN server, then of course this client is not pingable by a host outside the Virtual Private Network 192.168.1.0/24.